# Call generic method for std::variant

Tags: c++, std, std-variant

There are two classes with methods `f()` under the same name and signature:

```cpp
struct A {
    void f() {}
};
struct B {
    void f() {}
};
```

Is it possible having a `std::variant<A, B> v` to call this method with a single expression instead of `std::visit`?
Like `v->f()`?

Note: the question is specifically about `std::variant`. **NOT** about how to solve this particular task with without it (e.g. inheritance).

Comment: calling `std::visit` *is* 1 expression

Comment: Skip variants, and use templates? Or an argument-deducing lambda?

Comment: And what is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you think a variant would solve that problem? Please ask about that original and underlying problem directly instead.

Comment: i honestly don't understand whats wrong with `std::visit`. If you do not like to spell out a complicated expression too often you can always wrap it in a custom function. This question reads like "I know the solution, but I am looking for something else" without making clear what the requirements are or why the known solution is not ok

Comment: And until the underlying problem is explained, the answer would be: no there isn't, C++ does not work this way,

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number techically, you are correct : )

Comment: not only "technically". Are you trying to save keystrokes? is it lazyness of typing? what else?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because the question is about `variant` class and how to minimize the `visit` code for such cases. I do not ask to evaluate correctness of my solutions, I ask if there are any ways to make the `visit` compact.

Comment: "I ask if there are any ways for X to make Y compact". As I said, the way to get something with easier to spell out name is to write a custom function.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik this is a good answer. You can post it so I can accept.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes, I am trying to save keystrokes.

Comment: then you should say that. only one expression != as little characters to type as possible.

Comment: its a symptom of questions asking to avoid code or how to write code more terse that they do not show the code to be avoided or to be reduced but rather assume it would be obvious. If  the reason you didnt like `std::visit` is because you thought that you need to pass 1 lambda per type then you should tell us that, it isnt obvious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be worried about the number of characters you have to type. Minimizing typing is not a design goal of the language. `std::visit` is the way to do what you want. And because this is the way there is no reason to provide a different way that would achieve the same.

If you want the same with less typing you can always write a custom function:

```
void f(auto& v) {
     std::visit( [](auto& x) { x.f(); },v );
}
```

Then you can call it via `f(v);`. Its not exactly the desired `v->f();` but actually it has less characters to type.

---

PS: If this is for code golf, I want to refer you to this answer I wrote https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251154/114229. It is discussing the trade off between adding some code to make certain expressions shorter (the answer is specifically about using `#define` but the same considerations apply to writing a function).

PPS: If this is not for code golf, I want to remind you that code is written only once, but read many times. Everybody can read `std::visit(...)` and there is plenty of documentation on how it works and what it does. There is zero documentation for the function `f` above and it has a really poor name. Readability is more important than faster typing.

Comment: What if there are other methods?
Is it possible to wrap this into a template?
It doesn't look like so...

Comment: @hopeless-programmer I answered the quesiton you asked, taking into consideration what you said in comments. Calling  different methods would be a different question. Your `A` and `B`  have only 1 method. If you want to ask a follow up question you can open a new quesiton

Comment: @hopeless-programmer however, then it is even less clear why you want to avoid `std::visit`

Comment: With 5 classes and 4 identical methods each call will take 5 lambdas with exactly the same content inside. What is the point of duplicating the code?

Comment: @hopeless-programmer no. Why would you need 5 lambdas? You misunderstand something, but I cannot explain you why your code is wrong or unnecessary if you do not show the code. If you have an issue with 5 classes with 4 identical methods then you should open a new question to ask about that.

Comment: @hopeless-programmer oh well, I think I know what your misunderstanding is. If i am guessing right, look at the edit, it should already clarify something, 1 method, N different types -> only 1 lambda necessary

Comment: I never even imagined that this is possible with a single lambda. This is amazing! Thanks!

Comment: @hopeless-programmer https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit all the examples on the page are about passing 1 callable to `std::visit` that can accept any of the alternatives.